# Automated code style checking for AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs

I would like to know if at present there are any automated testing tools for checking coding style in AngularJS for a style guide such as:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

or otherwise, analgous to pep8 and pylint in Python.

Comment: The Brackets IDE (which I love because of it's live preview feature - change the code & the browser updates immediately - no need to save), has JS lint built in, but nothing Angular specific. http://brackets.io/

Comment: @Mawg - cool, thanks for the suggestion. I hope to give Brackets IDE a try.

Comment: Please remember to come back here and tell us what you think. It will help other searchers in the future.

Comment: @Mawg: Brackets looks quite promising, unfortunately for me it started freezing on startup immediately after loading a non-trivial html5 project and so I never got to play with it for more than a few minutes in total. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop with 4GB of RAM. I searched a bit online but couldn't find a hint as to the cause or solution.

Comment: These says, I would recommend Visual Studio Code